# Error en redirect url django

Tags: python, django

estoy iniciando un proyecto en django, el mismo al iniciar carga bien , el error surge cuando creo una url y un hipervinculo para rediriguir al mismo y se mantiene en la url iniciar, es decir no se redirigue.

Estructura de mi Proyecto:

```
carshop
 carshop
  -settings.py
  -urls.py
  ---
  --
 principal
  -urls.py
  -models.py
  -views.py
  ...
  ...
 static
 templates
```

en la urls.py de carshop:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from principal.views import Principal
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('principal.urls', namespace='principal')),
]
```

urls.py de principal:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from principal.views import Principal, MenuAdministrador
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', Principal, name='vista_principal'),
    url(r'^controlpanel', MenuAdministrador, name='controlpanel'),
]
```

en views.py de principal:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.template import loader


def Principal(request):

    template = loader.get_template('principal/index.html')
    context = {
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


def MenuAdministrador(request):

    template = loader.get_template('administrador/index.html')
    context = {
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

En mi template donde invoco tengo algo asi:

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'principal:controlpanel' %}" >Administrador</a>
```

Por defecto hago que cargue un template con imagenes tipo carrito de compras, lo cual lo hace bien, el problema surgue al seleccionar el vinculo Administrador no redirigue a la misma, se mantiene la pagina inicial estatica.

Quiza alguien me podria comentar cual es el error. gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las URLs en Django son expresiones regulares. Para que funcionen es necesario que agregues un inicio y final en la cadena que representa esa dirección URL. Para esto se usa `^` y `$` respectivamente:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from principal.views import Principal, MenuAdministrador
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Principal, name='vista_principal'),
    url(r'^controlpanel$', MenuAdministrador, name='controlpanel'),
]
```

Comment: Era tan facil, gracias me salvaste.. levaba un par de horas buscando solución..!!

Comment: @DiegoAvila qué bueno!